Autogenerated and unique id of type bigint in Azure databricks pyspark
I want to create an autogenerated id and it has to be unique across the job and of type Integer. If I use monotonically_increasing_id it generates unique id but only for the particular job run, when the next batch is running, it collides with the id.
I've couple of columns like batchid which is datetime stamp and if I concat 'monotonically_increasing_id' it could work but due to spark parallelism and bigint range could be an issue.
I have also tried window partition with runid (job id) as well, but it is not giving me the unique value.
I'm listing all the options I have tried, any help could be useful.
df = spark.table("table")
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("runid", "batchid").orderBy("batchid")

df.withColumn("id", (hash(concat(col("id"), lit("_"), col("batchid"), lit("_"), col("runid"))) % 10000000000).cast("bigint"))


df.withColumn("id", (abs(hash(concat(col("batchid"), lit("_"), monotonically_increasing_id(), lit("_")))) % 10000000000).cast("bigint"))

df = df.withColumn(
"Id",
(hash(concat(
    format_string("%010d", unix_timestamp(current_timestamp()) * 1000),  # Timestamp in milliseconds
    format_string("%05d", monotonically_increasing_id() % 100000),       # Ensuring uniqueness for the same millisecond, restrict to 5 digits
    concat_ws("_", *unique_cols)                                        # Concatenate the unique columns
)) + lit(2**31)).cast("bigint"))

df = df.withColumn("unique_id", 
               (monotonically_increasing_id() * 1000000000) +  
               (row_number().over(windowSpec) * 100000) +       
               col("runid").cast("bigint") +                    
               col("batchid").cast("bigint")) 


I tried this, and appears to be working good.
scale = 100000000000000 #10^14
df.withColumn("id",(monotonically_increasing_id() * scale +col("batch").cast("bigint")).cast("bigint"),)

This is working and dont find the collision. Batch is a timestamp.

monotonically_increasing_id() does not guarantee unique values across different job runs or multiple stages within the same job run.
It is not recommended to manually concatenate columns with monotonically_increasing_id() or other functions like current_timestamp() and row_number() to generate a unique ID. It may not guarantee uniqueness, especially when running in parallel.
Instead, you can consider using a combination of multiple columns to create a composite key that ensures uniqueness.
I have tried the below approach:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, col, lit, row_number
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
data = [
    ("2022-01-01", "Job1", "Data1"),
    ("2022-01-01", "Job1", "Data2"),
    ("2022-01-02", "Job1", "Data3"),
    ("2022-01-02", "Job2", "Data4"),
    ("2022-01-03", "Job2", "Data5"),
    ("2022-01-03", "Job2", "Data6"),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["batchid", "runid", "data"])
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("runid", "batchid").orderBy("batchid")
df = df.withColumn(
    "unique_id",
    concat(col("runid"), lit("_"), col("batchid"), lit("_"), row_number().over(windowSpec))
)
df.show()

Result:
+----------+-----+-----+-----------------+
|   batchid|runid| data|        unique_id|
+----------+-----+-----+-----------------+
|2022-01-01| Job1|Data1|Job1_2022-01-01_1|
|2022-01-01| Job1|Data2|Job1_2022-01-01_2|
|2022-01-02| Job1|Data3|Job1_2022-01-02_1|
|2022-01-02| Job2|Data4|Job2_2022-01-02_1|
|2022-01-03| Job2|Data6|Job2_2022-01-03_1|
|2022-01-03| Job2|Data5|Job2_2022-01-03_2|
+----------+-----+-----+-----------------+

In the above code, I used a combination of runid, batchid, and row_number() within a window function to generate a unique ID. This approach ensures uniqueness across different job runs and handles parallelism by using the window function to assign unique numbers within each partition defined by runid and batchid.
Using UUIDs (org.apache.spark.sql.functions.uuid()), UUIDs guarantee uniqueness across different nodes and job runs.
Here is an example:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
data = [("Alice", 34), ("Bob", 45), ("Charlie", 37)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["name", "age"])
df_with_uuid = df.withColumn("uuid", expr("uuid()"))
df_with_uuid.show(truncate=False)

Results:
+-------+---+------------------------------------+
|name   |age|uuid                                |
+-------+---+------------------------------------+
|Alice  |34 |1634bc71-bec0-4efe-a2f4-793c363110d5|
|Bob    |45 |7ec2f25f-da0e-42ac-a52a-c665ccc12350|
|Charlie|37 |b2881250-8b5d-4ec8-8121-d6ec7690416e|
+-------+---+------------------------------------+

As you mentioned, the problem is that the ID has to be of type bigint. You can try generating a unique ID of type bigint while ensuring uniqueness across job runs by using a combination of columns along with hashing.
I have tried the md5 function to hash the concatenated string, but the results were NULL. This is because the md5 function in PySpark does not support hashing values with a data type of BigInt. To work around this, you can cast the ID column to a string data type before applying the md5 function.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat_ws, md5
df = df.withColumn("unique_id", concat_ws("_", col("runid"), col("batchid"), col("data")))
df = df.withColumn("id", md5(col("unique_id").cast("string")))

+----------+-----+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|   batchid|runid| data|           unique_id|                  id|
+----------+-----+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|2022-01-01| Job1|Data1|Job1_2022-01-01_D...|fffdd2babb8e9b60b...|
|2022-01-01| Job1|Data2|Job1_2022-01-01_D...|b8a430deba3f61223...|
|2022-01-02| Job1|Data3|Job1_2022-01-02_D...|3af865f308eff7fb8...|
|2022-01-02| Job2|Data4|Job2_2022-01-02_D...|56537c8a822bd1b7f...|
|2022-01-03| Job2|Data5|Job2_2022-01-03_D...|092dd4548f93e0070...|
|2022-01-03| Job2|Data6|Job2_2022-01-03_D...|8e7171be80fe94097...|
+----------+-----+-----+--------------------+--------------------+

By casting the ID column to string (col("unique_id").cast("string")), the md5 function will receive a string input.

Thanks, but the problem is the ID has to be of type bigint, that is the rule what is given.

it is still string, but I need in bigint
